# How to add a whole list of elements into one list?

Tags: python, list

This is my code. I have to add a whole list of things here:(http://pastebin.com/u5S0rF9D) into a list, how do I do that? this is my excel file that I imported into python (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Atza5UMAhSHRdHJMWGZqZlRrZWpySnU1SHhKOXFlN2c#gid=0) 
What do I "append" into the maleList?

```
import random

gender = raw_input("Enter your character gender (Male/Female): ")
start = raw_input("Enter Please enter starting letter of name(A to B): ")

import csv
readerFileHandle = open("Book1.csv", "rb")
malenames = csv.reader(readerFileHandle)
for row in malenames:
    y = []
    for x in row:
        if x[-1] == '\xa0':
            y.append(x[:-2])
        else:
            y.append(x)
    for z in y:       
        print z
maleList = []
maleList.append()
print maleList 
readerFileHandle.close()
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: Are you looking for `list.extend`?

Comment: Nope, my teacher said this is able to put all the names into the list

Comment: There's no problem, it's just that i don't know how to append that whole list into the maleList

Comment: Are you looking for `maleList += y` after the `print z` and unindented one tab? (You will need to move `maleList = []` to be above your `for row in malenames`)

Comment: I tried what CollinJSimpson, but I only got 3 elements added into the list.

Comment: `'\xa0'` is one character, do you mean to trim 2 off using `[:-2]`? You could perhaps use `x.rstrip('\xa0')` instead.

Comment: '\xa0' is a value that appeared suddely, I did that to remove it.

Comment: Right, but your code is removing the character before `'\xa0'` as well. Eg line 5 of your output is "Jac" instead of "Jace"

Answer (score 2):

If you want them all in one list like the paste bin, just append them directly

```
malenames = csv.reader(readerFileHandle)
maleList = []
for row in malenames:
    for x in row:
        maleList.append(x.rstrip('\xa0'))
```

You could instead write that as a list comprehension

```
malenames = csv.reader(readerFileHandle)
maleList = [x.rstrip('\xa0') for row in malenames for x in row]
```

Edit: looks like there is a combo `'\xc2\xa0'` attached to the end of some of the entries. So it should be `x.rstrip('\xc2\xa0')` to clean them properly

Comment: I think that the original code was trying to strip \x0d\x0a from the last entry.

Comment: @SteveBarnes, well `x.rstrip('\xd0\x0a')` would work in that case. Likely even `x.rstrip()` will do. However the output seems to have stripped the last character off a bunch of entries.

Comment: Just looking at the original code it had `if x[-1] == '\xa0':
            y.append(x[:-2])`

Comment: @SteveBarnes, I just downloaded the book1 as csv and it is `'\xa0'` not `'\x0a'`. Perhaps someone did a typo in the program that generated it.

Comment: I suspect that it is one of the Micro$oft .csv 'features' mentioned in the python docs.

Comment: @SteveBarnes, indeed - seems it is a nonbreaking space

Answer (score 0):

if you have a=[1,2] and b=[3,4], and want list b to be appended to list a, then

```
>>> a=[1,2]
>>> b=[3,4]
>>> a.extend(b)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: extend is not what I am looking for because I do not have a list for all the names.